# Full Calendar: not able to select today's slots

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using **FullCalendar - JavaScript Event Calendar**
for event management, everything is working fine but when I try to select today's date slot, for example, suppose today is 7 August 2017 and time now is 3:45 pm when I try to select a slot for today only from 7 - 8 pm it is not allowing me to select but when I try to select tomorrows or day after tomorrows slots it working there and then again if I try to select today's slot it is also working fine it allows me to select today's slot after trying to tomorrow, this is something weird behavior but I don't know why it is happening the same happening on my Mobile App with the same plugin where I have used Cordova.

below is my fullcalendar object:

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        height:"parent",
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        buttonIcons :{
            prev:'ion-chevron-left',
            next:'ion-chevron-right'
        },
        defaultView:'agendaWeek',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: false,
        resize: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        dragScroll: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        slotDuration:'00:15:00',
        forceEventDuration:true,
        selectOverlap:false,
        eventOverlap:true,
        selectLongPressDelay:500,
        timezone:'local',
```

Comment: You can use eventConstraint : { start : '0:00', end : '24:00 }

Comment: please let me know once you tried :)

Comment: @hsnbl eventConstraint is not working the same problem no luck :( 

is there any workaround?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle example with your code

Comment: I observed one thing on mobile devices when I try to select slot for afternoon or evening fullcalendar always select morning slots like 7-8 or 6-7 am morning is there any event for touch devices